# SQL Query count how many products bought on one day by those who bought more than 3 products on a different day

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query to count how many chairs were bought on 2015-01-01 by those who bought 2 or more of any products on 2016-01-01

Tables:

Sales (date, customer_id, product_id, units_sold)

Products (id, name, price)

Customers (id, name)

My SQL code so far:

```
SELECT sum(s.units_sold)
FROM Sales s, Products p
WHERE p.name = 'Chair' and s.date = '2015-01-01' and s.product_id = p.id;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0b56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient, but produces the desired results

```
SELECT sum(s.units_sold)
FROM Sales s, Products p
WHERE p.name = 'Chair' and s.date = '2015-01-01' and s.product_id = p.id
AND s.customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Sales WHERE date = '2016-01-01' AND units_sold > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use two levels of aggregation, the first at the customer level and the second overall:

```
SELECT SUM(chairs_2015)
FROM (SELECT s.customer_id,
             SUM(CASE WHEN p.name = 'Chair' and s.date = '2015-01-01
                      THEN s.units_sold
                 END) as chairs_2015,
      FROM Sales s JOIN
           Products p
           ON s.product_id = p.id
      WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN s.date = '2016-01-01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
      GROUP BY s.customer_id
     ) s;
```